# Spectrum of a time-domain impulse train

Tags: theory

I am trying to learn DSP. I'm reading the 2nd edition of Oppenheim & Schafer's "Discrete-Time Sig. Proc." book. On the topic of converting a continuous signal to a discrete-time signal the idea of a time-domain $s(t)$ impulse train is discussed, where $s(t)$ is defined as:

$$s(t) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \delta\left(t - nT\right)$$

where variable $T$ is the time between the impulses. Next I read, from Oppenheim & Schafer's equation (4.5) on page 143, that the spectrum of $s(t)$ is:

\begin{align}S(j\omega) &= \frac{2\pi}{T}\sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \delta\left(\omega - k\omega_s\right)\\&=\omega_s \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \delta\left(\omega - k\omega_s\right)\end{align}

where $\omega_s$ is the sampling frequency in radians/second. That $S(j\omega)$ expression has a scaling factor of $\omega_s$. My questions are: Does that $\omega_s$ scaling factor mean that the $S(j\omega)$ impulses in the frequency domain have amplitudes proportional to the sampling frequency? What is the physical meaning of that $\omega_s$ scaling factor? Does it even have a physical meaning?

Comment: I wouldn't get too caught up in the "physical meaning" as this is just a mathematical model for how sampling works, anyway.  The factor of $\omega_s$ just falls out of the application of the discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) to the time-domain impulse train. You often end up with scale factors like these; they are necessary in order to satisfy [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem).

Comment: @Jason R: The $s(t)$ function, the time impulses, is a continuous function. Is it possible to apply the DTFT to a continuous function?

Comment: I was a bit hasty in my explanation earlier; I don't have O&S in front of me right now, but you can get to $S(j\omega)$ by expanding $s(t)$ in a Fourier series, not using the DTFT. The DTFT is the natural extension of this: once you note that the function $s(t)$ has no useful information at instants other than at $t = nT$ for integer $n$, you then take its samples at those instants only, turning $s(t)$ into $s[n]$, which you can then apply the DTFT to; you end up getting the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think of it in terms of the relationship between a sampled analog signal $x_a(t)$ to its discrete discrete-time signal $x(n)$  (at period $T$) and their spectrum relationship:
\begin{align}x(n)&=x_a(nT)\\X(F)&=F_s\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty X_a(F - kF_s)\end{align}
With $T = \frac 1F$. Think of the sampled version as any continuous signal $\textit{sifted}$ by the impulse train.

The spectrum on the LHS is a periodic function of $F$ consisting of a sum of shifted (by integer multiples of $F_s$) and **scaled** replicas of $X_a(F)$. To be strict mathematically, the scaling must be there. So yes, proportional to $F_s$. But in most real-world applications, scaling factors are skipped to save computation. As to its physical meaning, I don't know if there is any. Kinda baffling though when inspecting units with the scaling, one is tempted to say that each term in the summation is in $\textrm{[unit/Hz]}$.

Anyways, the two formulas are very useful in ideal sampling and reconstruction.